# Why is this cyclic subgroup normal?

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking at the following solution:

[image]

I'm just wondering...how do we know that $\langle x \rangle$ is normal?

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is abelian, then all its subgroups are normal.